# Regex google analytics - Filter some directories and pages from url

Tags: regex

I need to create a view in google analytics that can filter some pages.

The current regex I am using is:

> ^/(|es|pt|fr|de|blog|examples|about|)?(/(\w*)?)?$

Pages I want to show:

```
/
/es
/es/
/es/something-else
/blog/blog-post-123
/about
/examples
/examples/directory
/examples/directory/title-examples
```

Pages I don't want to show:

```
/any-other-url-not-mentioned
/es1231
/esad
/examplesee
/blogbla-bla-bala
/blog-bla-bla-ba
```

The current problem with my regex is if the page contains "**-**" it will NOT show up in the view:

```
/blog/10-tools 
page/this-is-content-url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work:

```
^\/(es|pt|fr|de|blog|examples|about)?($|\/).*
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yeo4q5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^\/(es|pt|fr|de|blog|examples|about)?(\/[^\/]+)*\/?$
```

Or

```
^\/((es|pt|fr|de|blog|examples|about)(\/[^\/]+)*\/?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q3zuWX/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Q3zuWX/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\/` - a `/`
- `(es|pt|fr|de|blog|examples|about)?` - an optional group matching any of the alternative substrings in it
- `(\/[^\/]+)*` - 0+ `/` followed with 1+ chars other than `/`
- `\/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string

The second regex is a bit more precise since it won't match `//`, but it does not seem a valid scenario.